# I dont want to see dotted lines in Expander Header edges

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

1- Create **wpf** application.

2- Add three WPF Windows to the project as **Window1**, **Window2** and **Window3**

3- Copy and paste following xaml codes into **MainWindow**.

```
<Grid>
    <Expander VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ExpandDirection="Up" Background="Gold" >
        <Expander.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Menu"/>
        </Expander.Header>
        <StackPanel Width="180">
            <Button x:Name="Button1" Height="25" Content="Button1"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button2" Height="25" Content="Button2"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button3" Height="25" Content="Button3"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

4- Copy and paste following **vb.net** codes into **MainWindow** code behind.

```
Class MainWindow 
Private Sub MainWindow_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Key = Key.F1 Then
        Dim myWindow1 As New Window1()
        myWindow1.Show()
    End If

    If e.Key = Key.F2 Then
        Dim myWindow2 As New Window2()
        myWindow2.Show()
    End If

    If e.Key = Key.F3 Then
        Dim myWindow3 As New Window3()
        myWindow3.Show()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

**C# codes are here**

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Key == Key.F1))
        {
            Window1 myWindow1 = new Window1();
            myWindow1.Show();
        }

        if ((e.Key == Key.F2))
        {
            Window2 myWindow2 = new Window2();
            myWindow2.Show();
        }

        if ((e.Key == Key.F3))
        {
            Window3 myWindow3 = new Window3();
            myWindow3.Show();
        }

    }
}
```

5- Run this project, then *expand* that **Expander**, then *press* **F2**, then *close* **Window2**.

My question:

I dont want to see dotted lines in **Expander Header edges** as you can see here: https://prnt.sc/m2oi2n

**Note:** I have tried following codes but they are not working.

```
IsTabStop="False" Focusable="False" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
```

Comment: A Handles clause in a WPF App?

Comment: Is this wrong? `Private Sub MainWindow_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown`

Comment: The WPF default code looks like `private void Window_KeyDown(sender Object, e KeyEventArgs)` and in the XAML `KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" ` If yours works I guess it is not wrong.

Comment: The C# code above is converted from vb.net. I am vb.net expert, and I have no idea about C#.

Comment: In vb.net `Private Sub Window_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)`  in XAML `KeyDown="Window_KeyDown"`

Comment: There is no difference. Both work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dotted rectangle you see is defined by the FocusVisualStyle on ToggleButton in expander default control template. You can clone and edit the control template by right clicking on the control (Visual Studio 2017) and selecting Edit Template > Edit Copy. Then alter the ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual style.